# Ignore nativeWindow event listener

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, mouseevent, nativewindow

This has been bugging me for days, cant seem to get an answer after googling forever...

Problem is simple,

I have a rectangle with an event listener like so:

```
rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMove);

private function startMove(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    this.nativeWindow.startMove();
}
```

this works fine.

I also have a button inside this rectangle, and when I click the button the window drags just like if I had clicked on the rectangle.

How can I stop this from happening? I tried removing the event but that didn't work, I don't even know which event to remove, the mouseDown or NativeDrag event... There is no stopDrag() function in nativeWindow. Is there a simple solution?

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to only process the event if the event's `target` (where it originated from) is the dispatcher you were listening to.  The dispatcher is identified via `event.currentTarget`.  So this is what your code needs to look like:

```
rect.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startMove);

private function startMove(event:MouseEvent):void
{
   if (event.target == event.currentTarget)
      this.nativeWindow.startMove();
}
```

*P.S. I notice you're new to Stack Overflow - welcome!  If you find my answer useful, please be sure to upvote it and accept it via the green checkmark*

Comment: Perfect solution! Could not imagine it to be any simpler. I only had to add ".parent" to event.target